# Core Data Conundrum: Cannot call NSFetchedResults twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a custom UITableViewController, called mainViewController.

It has a public property in the header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *someGroups;
```

This property is set in the `viewDidLoad` method

```
_someGroups = [[GGGroups findAllSortedBy:@"lastUpdated" ascending:NO withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", [GGUser currentUser]]] mutableCopy];
```

However, for some reason, *if I ever call the following, once the view has loaded, it returns 0 objects*.

```
[[GGGroups findAllSortedBy:@"lastUpdated" ascending:NO withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", [GGUser currentUser]]] mutableCopy];
```

This is quite annoying especially when I want to `reloadData` in the table view controller, since this array is the data source, so the table view becomes blank since this method returns 0 objects now.

I am currently using MagicalRecord, does anyone know why this occurs.

Thank you!

Comment: So what happens when you step into that method? You've got the MagicalRecord code, and MR_findAllSortedBy:... isn't terribly complicated, so step in and figure out *why* your fetch request is failing. Is an error occurring? Is the context nil?

Comment: I don't know how to step into a method call, sorry I'm making my first iOS app, so I am new to some stuff @Caleb

Comment: You'll find [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/060-Debug_and_Tune_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW40) in the [Xcode User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/000-About_Xcode/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH1-SW1), accessible from the handy Help menu in Xcode itself. Spending an hour or two learning to use the debugger will help you more than Stack Overflow ever could.

Comment: Oh, I see , I kinda knew how to do that,  I just had never looked at the stack trace, just the console, thanks @Caleb

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in MagicalRecord that caches your find* requests. Every call to any of the find methods will generate a new request and perform a new fetch on that new request. My guesses as to why your second fetch is failing:

1. The default context (which you are implicitly using by not specifying one) is nil somehow
2. Your currentUser method is returning nil
3. Your data store is empty on that second call
4. You aren't actually calling your method to reload data at the right time
5. You are not refreshing your view of data

MagicalRecord has logging built in. I suggest turning it on and seeing if there are any errors that show up in the logs. Those will help pinpoint any issues that might be arising with Core Data.

Comment: 2,3,4,5 are all ok, so I guess the defaultContext is nil for some reason, how do I un-nil it?

Comment: Are you sure? You can specify a context explicitly using the (optional) inContext: parameter on every find method. Make a context that isn't nil, and try that.